# Change model attribute name based on status?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a `Match` model that has `3` users: an `observer`, a `player1`, and a `player2`, and a `status` enum (which could be `finished` or `pending`).

When the `Match` is `finished`, I want to be able to access the `winner` of the match (which would be either `player1` or `player2`), and the `loser`.

The easiest way I know to implement this would be to store 5 user references, but that doesn't sound good.

The other would be to implement the `winner, loser, winner=, loser=` etc methods on my own in the model, but that's what ActiveRecord is for...

Any suggestions?

Current code:

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord
  validates :observer, :player1, :player2, :status, presence: true

  belongs_to :observer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'observer_id'
  belongs_to :player1, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'player1_id'
  belongs_to :player2, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'player2_id'

  enum status: [:pending, :finished]
end
```

**E: My problem is not how to implement this, I know a few ways, my problem is implementing this in such a way where I don't know to manually hook stuff up (i.e, writing accessors for `winner,loser` etc).**

Comment: Can you post the code for what your `Match` model currently looks like? _(the pieces related to this question)_

Comment: @jeffdill2 Sure, it's a really small class at the moment, just posted it.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having two Models here. One for `Match` & `User`. Both having status columns, and an association that match has many users. When `Match` changes from `pending` to `finished` state, change the `User` status from `playing` to `winner` or `looser`. That way you can query the winners and looser easily.

Comment: then change `has_many` to `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between match and user

Comment: Yeah, but a user could be a `winner` in a match and a `loser` in another.

Comment: Then you can add a has_many through relation for match and users with `match_users` model which has a user_status column. This way users will have different status for different matches.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what, somewhere you're going to have to store who the winner was. However, since there's only two players in the match, the good news is that you don't need to also store the loser because it'll always simply be whichever player is not the winner.

Here's a couple of different ways you could implement this:

---

#### 1.

Have a `winner` column (formatted as a string) specify the association of who won, i.e. `"player1"` or `"player2"`. Then you could create a `winner()` method to override the return value of the attribute (to give you the actual `User` object) like so:

```
def winner
  send(read_attribute(:winner))
end
```

Then, your `loser()` method could look like this:

```
def loser
  player1 == winner ? player2 : player1
end
```

With this approach, you have don't have to declare additional associations but the trade off is some messiness:

1. Assigning the value of the `winner` field can be awkward and prone to human error (i.e. typos).
2. It's dangerous because you're storing string values to represent the name of an association that could change – i.e. if you ever decide to change the name of the associations to `player_one` and `player_two`, the whole thing breaks unless you also update your data.
3. Determining the loser requires both player1 *and* player2 `User` objects to be instantiated to determine which one is the loser.

---

#### 2.

To me, the cleanest and most "Railsy" way to accomplish this would be to simply have a `winner_id` column. This would give you one additional association:

```
belongs_to :winner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'winner_id'
```

This may seem redundant but it enables you to do a few things:

You can assign the winner simply by doing `@match.winner = @match.player1` or `@match.winner = @match.player2`.

You can easily find the loser by doing:

```
def loser
  winner_id == player1_id ? player2 : player1
end
```

which *doesn't* require both player `User` objects to be instantiated to return the loser.

You can have sane/testable data validations:

```
validate :winner_is_player_in_match

private

def winner_is_player_in_match
  unless [player1_id, player2_id].include?(winner_id)
    errors.add(:winner, 'must be one of the players in the match.')
  end
end
```